# Explicit Override Using Automatic Property

Tags: c#, c++-cli, automatic-properties, explicit-interface, explicit-implementation

I'm trying to use a C++/CLI auto-implemented property to explicitly override an interface.  In particular, I have written (in C++/CLI)

```
interface IInterface
{
    property Object ^MyProperty
    {
        Object ^get(void);
        void set(Object^);
    }
    void Method(void);
}
```

To explicitly consume `IInterface` in C#, one would write

```
class MyClass : IInterface
{
    Object IInterface.MyProperty { get; set;}
    void IInterface.Method()
    {
    }
}
```

C++/CLI does not support EII, but it does support explicit overrides.  For example, one can write

```
sealed ref class MyClass : IInterface
{
private:
    virtual void method(void) = IInterface::Method {}
public:
    property Object ^MyProperty;
}
```

I want to define my explicit override using an auto-implemented property, but

```
sealed ref class MyClass : IInterface
{
private:
    virtual void method(void) = IInterface::Method {}
    property Object ^myProperty = IInterface::MyProperty;
}
```

yields the compiler errors `C2146`: Missing `;` before identifier `Object`, `C2433`: `virtual` not permitted on data declarations, `C4430`: Missing type specifier, and `C3766`: Interface member not implemented.  Am I missing something?  What is the appropriate C++/CLI syntax to achieve what I seek?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use a basic (i.e: auto-implemented) property with a different name to implement an interface property explicitly. However, your explicitly implemented property can refer to a basic property.

```
interface class IInterface
{
    property Object^ Property
    {
        Object^ get();
        void set(Object^ value);
    }
};

ref class MyClass sealed : IInterface
{
public:
    property String^ MyProperty;
private:
    virtual property Object^ UntypedProperty
    {
        Object^ get() sealed = IInterface::Property::get {
            return MyProperty;
        }

        void set(Object^ value) sealed = IInterface::Property::set {
            MyProperty = value->ToString();
        }
    }
};
```